# jquery - why is my form submitting when it's supposed to be making ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

when I submit my form, I expect an ajax call to shoe in the console, and the page url to remain the same...
But the form action is taken and the http call changes the url.

```
<head>
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $( '#myForm' ).submit( function() {
                $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                    type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                    url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
                    success: function(response) { // on success..
                        $('#resultsDiv').html(response); // update the DIV
                    }
                return false;
            });

        }); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="myFormDiv" >
        <form name="myform" id="myform" action="form_handeler.cfm" method="post"  >
            <input type="text" size="100" name="shoe" value="" /> <input type="submit" name="myFormSubmit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="resultsDiv" >

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code not enclosed properly with `});`, i.e your script has error due to `});` so that your script not executed as you expected, so that default form submission takes place.

```
   $(function() {
        $('#myform').submit( function() {
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                ...
            }); //HERE
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to prevent the default action from happening, which is form submit.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( '#myform' ).submit( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                $('#resultsDiv').html(response); // update the DIV
            }

        //return false; - You dont need the return false here if you are using preventDefault.
    });

});
```

});

Read more on [`event.preventDefault` here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score 2):

What if we don't you use `<form>` tag? :D
Here's my solution :
HTML:

```
<input type="text" size="100" id="shoe" value="" />
<input type="submit" onclick="myFormSubmit()" value="submit" />
```

Javascript :

```
    function myFormSubmit(){
      var shoe = $("#shoe").val();
                  $.ajax({                         // create an AJAX call...
                        data: "shoe="+shoe,        // get the form data
                        type: "POST",              // GET or POST
                        url: "form_handeler.cfm",  // the file to call
                        success: function(response) 
                        {                          // on success..
                            $('#resultsDiv').html(response); // update the DIV
                        }

                 });
   return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in the script, also the id is `myform` not `myForm`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
            success: function (response) { // on success..
                $('#resultsDiv').html(response); // update the DIV
            }
        });
        return false;//this was placed within the ajax options
    });
});//this was missing
```

Answer (score 1):

Close your paranthesis:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( '#myform' ).submit( function() {
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    $('#resultsDiv').html(response); // update the DIV
                } //ADD THIS TOO
            }); //HERE
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix this in the HTML...

```
<input type="button" name="myFormSubmit" value="submit" />
```

And this in your script...

```
$( '#myFormSubmit' ).click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    data: $('#myform').serialize(), // get the form data
    type: $('#myform).attr('method'), // GET or POST
    url: $('#myform).attr('action'), // the file to call
    success: function(response) { // on success..
      $('#resultsDiv').html(response); // update the DIV
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

...but be warned that there's really know reason to have all the form attributes populated if you plan to use an AJAX call to process the form's data.